# Can one express these R functions more succinctly? cumcsum()

Tags: r

I just recently started out with R, and got a feeling I am doing things way too long-winded.

I wrote lines to turn one column of given time intervals in milliseconds into a new column in seconds, and then turning this one into column of timepoints with `cumsum()`

How can one simplify these line of code for example:

```
dat <- readLines(x)

dat2 <- dat[-(1:8)]

dat3 <- list(dat2)

dat4 <- as.data.frame(dat3,row.names = NULL,col.names = "Time",
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

dat4$Time <- as.numeric(dat4$Time)

dat5 <- mutate(dat4, Time2= Time/1000)

dat6 <- data.frame(dat5,Time3=cumsum(dat5$Time2))

dat7 <- select(dat6,Time3)
```

Comment: Provide reproducible data. What is x? The `readLines()` function will read successive lines as character data. Perhaps you want `read.csv()` or `read.delim()` which will skip lines at the beginning, read the column, identify it as numeric, and produce a data frame in one step. See the manual page `?read.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "x" is a text file with a single column of values preceded by 6 rows of non-numeric information:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="X
Y
Z
A
B
C
1000
1200
2000
5000
3000", skip=6, header=FALSE, col.names="Time", colClasses="numeric")
dat
#   Time
# 1 1000
# 2 1200
# 3 2000
# 4 5000
# 5 3000
```

You should replace `text=" . . . "` with the name of your file in quotation marks, e.g. "file.txt".

Then your data frame is

```
dat <- data.frame(Time=dat$Time, Time2=dat$Time/1000, Time3=cumsum(dat$Time/1000))
dat
#       Time Time2 Time3
# 1     1000   1.0   1.0
# 2     1200   1.2   2.2
# 3     2000   2.0   4.2
# 4     5000   5.0   9.2
# 5     3000   3.0  12.2
```